# How to add new functions to a COM .dll created by a Visual Studio C++ ATL Project

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I'm trying to create a very basic COM dll for inclusion in a C# project, to then use to wrap up some C++ functionality into a COM module for inclusion in a C# project (the language used by the rest of the code base).

I included the COM dll, added a class to the COM dll and instantiated it in the C# code, but so far I haven't been able to add new functionality to the new class.

Here's what I did:

1. New Visual C# Windows Forms Application
2. Right click solution->Add->New Project...
3. Add New Visual C++ ATL Project (called MyCOMDLL)
4. Default options chosen in ATL Project Wizard (I've also tried ticking 'Support COM+ 1.0')
5. Right click MyCOMDLL project->Add->Class
6. Add New Visual C++ ATL COM+ 1.0 Component
7. Typed 'MyCOMObject' into Short name, which automatically populated the other fields in the 'Names' tab
8. Left the other settings as default
9. Built the MyCOMDLL project
10. Add a reference to the new MyCOMDLL.dll to the C# Windows Forms Application

    Right Click C# Windows Forms Application Project->Properties

    On the Build tab set Platform target to x86

    Add "using MyCOMDLLLib;" to Form1.cs file

    Add a button to the Form and in the button click function add

```
MyCOMDLLLib.MyCOMObjectClass myVariable = new MyCOMObjectClass();
```

I've tried various things so won't list any except the most obvious here - I tried adding a class method to MyCOMObject.h:

```
// CMyCOMObject
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyCOMObject :
    public CComObjectRootEx,
    public CComCoClass,
    public IDispatchImpl
{
public:
    CMyCOMObject()
    {
    }
```

```
DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

HRESULT FinalConstruct()
{
    return S_OK;
}

void FinalRelease()
{
}
```

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_MYCOMOBJECT)

DECLARE_NOT_AGGREGATABLE(CMyCOMObject)

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CMyCOMObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IMyCOMObject)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
END_COM_MAP()

// IMyCOMObject
public:
    // SB: My attempt at adding a new method
    int ReturnTwo()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

The ReturnTwo method was visible in the class view of CMyCOMObject, but not visible in the class view of MyCOMObjectClass in the C# Windows Forms Application project.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried adding a class method to MyCOMObject.h

That's not good enough.  The super important file in your project is the .idl file (Interface Description Language).  That file generates the type library that gets embedded in the DLL.  The type library is what .NET uses to generate the managed import library.  Your added function won't be in there because you didn't modify the .idl file.

Modifying interfaces is a painful if you do it by hand, there are three places that need to be edited.  The .idl, the .h and the .cpp file.  It is best done with the wizard.  From the Class View window, right-click the interface (like IFoo), Add, Add Method (or Property).  Then switch to the .cpp file to write the implementation of the method.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!  Successfully used the wizard to add methods and properties which were visible in the C# app, though as an FYI for anyone else you'll need to get rid of the previously generated interop DLL when adding methods/properties.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy your new build of the dll over into the C# project again?

Comment: Tried deleting the reference from the C# project, deleting the generated Interop.MyCOMDLLLib.dll and re-adding the reference.  Also tried adding a function and a variable to the .dll before building and adding to the C# project in the first place.  No joy in either case.

Comment: Figured. Just worth a try. You might be having problems with COM registration. You usually need to register dlls for COM, I think C# only does it automatically if you build the dll in C# as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Sogger. Unfortunately I'm pretty sure it's not a registration issue.  I did have some registration related problems earlier. Setting the C# project to build for x86 and (not previously mentioned) running Visual Studio as an Administrator made those go away.  I don't think I would be able to instantiate the class at run time without registering the COM dll.

Comment: Well, I was thinking you could instantiate your class through an old version of the interface previously registered, which could explain your problem.